# How to specify full path for postgres FTS .syn file?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, synonym

In the example from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY):

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY syn (template=synonym, synonyms='synonym_sample');
```

I want to be able to specify a full path for the `.syn` file, instead of the default `$SHAREDIR/synonym_sample`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) you cited:

> The only parameter required by the synonym template is `SYNONYMS`, which is the **base name of its configuration file** — my_synonyms in the above example. The file's full name will be `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/my_synonyms.syn` (where `$SHAREDIR` means the PostgreSQL installation's shared-data directory).

(emphasis mine)

You are supposed to place your dictionnaries in that specific directory. I guess this is just for file privileges handling (the user running the PostgreSQL process must have access to this directory) and standardization. You can choose the name, but not the location of the file.

Comment: I was hoping I could create and update the dictionary from a temp table or maybe a file that could be kept in version control. I guess this is not possible :(

Comment: I am afraid it is not. Also, PostgreSQL *probably* reads the `synonym` file just the first time it needs it, and doesn't reload it any more until it is stopped and restarted.